# There is no php-fpm.sock file in MacBook m1

Tags: php, nginx

I have MacBook Air m1 and macOS Monterey.PHP 8.1.6 and Nginx Installed. I can not find php-fpm-sock file and php files does not work at all just downloading by itself instead execute..

ls /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.1
[image]